# Liferay Portal 6.0 CE: missing src folder and web.xml in skeleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, skeleton-code

I use Liferay Portal 6.0 CE and SDK6.0.6 for portlet development.

To create a directory structure, I use the following command:

```
create.bat <project name> "<portlet title>"
```

However, the 'src' directory and the 'web.xml' is not created. I see only 'classes' directory.

I know that the directory structure should be as follows:

[image]

If I add a class to the 'src' directory, I get the following when building:

```
build-common-plugin.xml:347 ...
build-common.xml:90 ...
```

Some Ant task is called from 'build-common-plugin.xml' that references to the 'scr' directory:

```
<mkdir dir="docroot/WEB-INF/client/src" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check a folder `\tools\portlet_tmpl` in sdk.. This contains the template to create a new portlet.

You can have your `src` folder here and all other subsequent portlets will have src folder.